# Passing value from CloudKit app to another user

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sharing, cloudkit

I am new in CloudKit and just now analyzing CloudKitAtlas from Developer Library.
I create app where i want to "share" data to another user of the same app.

I have CKContainer in private database, where user put all his created dictionaries. Now i want to give him possibility to share some part of his data to another user (create public containerWithIdentifier) . I know is possible to check every email address from address book and get result who have that app installed. So user can choose who will be able to see his data.

**The question is how to tell another user app "look to that CKContainer on my shared data"** :)

Anyone already do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can list all users from your addresbook that has the app installed using the container discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler method. It will return an array from which you can get an recordID. If you want to share something with one of those users, then create a record where you put that ID in a to field. On startup of your app you will have created a subscription with a predicate that looks for that TO field and compare that to your own user recordId. So if a record is created with your ID in the TO field, then you will receive a notification. Whatever you want to send to an other user must be in the public database. I am working on something like this. The code can be found at https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao (work in progress)

Comment: That project does't work for me and i am coding in Objective-C only, so i have to try do it my way :) but vote-up for your help anyway..

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for downloading the dependencies using cocoapods?

Comment: Nope.. I just checked your code. That program will be something like messenger?

Comment: yes, the messenger will be the demo for the CloudKit dao. As I said, its a work in progress. Still a lot to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check the CKContainer.h in CloudKit framework, they discover people in your contacts by their email address. If that email address in contacts is not the email address to login apple id (or icloud account?), I guess it can not match.

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, CKApplicationPermissions) {
    /* Allows the user's record in CloudKit to be discoverable via the user's email address */
    CKApplicationPermissionUserDiscoverability         = 1 << 0,
} NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
```